# Charged particles accelerating toward one another gain both kinetic and potential energy

Tags: electricity, charge, potential, coulombs-law

If we have two particles (let's just say of equal but opposite charges, $-q$ and $q$) and place them a distance $r$ apart, the potential energy of the system is:

$$
U = k \frac{q^2}{r}
$$

Now if we let time continue, the particles start to accelerate toward one another (and the acceleration itself is also increasing, but regardless).

We can find the kinetic energy as

$$
K = \frac{1}{2} mv^2
$$

And the potential energy increase as time goes on, because $r$ (the distance between the particles) decreases over time.

So both $K$ and $U$ are increasing. Where is this energy coming from?

My current thought process is this:

We get the formula for electrical potential energy by integrating the formula for electric force with respect to $r$:

$$
U = kq^2 \int \frac{1}{r^2} dr = -k \frac{q^2}{r}
$$

Therefore potential energy is negative and is decreasing over time. But I can't find a negative sign for potential energy in any formulas I've come across.

And anyway, if the charges were repulsive, this would still not conserve energy, as potential energy would increase again.

Comment: Take a look at [the correct formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy#One_point_charge_q_in_the_presence_of_another_point_charge_Q). When the two charges have opposite sign, their potential energy is negative.

Comment: Double check your expression for $U$.

Comment: Where did you find your incorrect formula?

Comment: @Ghoster I was just under the impression that the sign of each charge doesn't matter, because of how we use the Coulomb's law. But it now makes sense; if the charges are equal, potential energy must act differently if the charges are opposite.

Comment: *the sign of each charge doesn't matter, because of how we use the Coulomb's law* When I use Coulomb’s Law, the sign of the charges matters a lot: Same-sign charges repel, while opposite-sign charges attract. This repulsion or attraction leads to positive or negative electrostatic potential energy.

Comment: Why are you squaring $q$? They are separate charges.

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition of the potential energy is $$U=k\frac{q_1 q_2}{r}$$ For equal and opposite charges this becomes $$U=-k\frac{q^2}{r}$$ Thus as KE increases PE decreases.